# Looking for a qcow2 RHEL6/RHEL7 image that uploads to a Bluemix Virtual Server

Tags: image, upload, ibm-cloud, rhel, virtual-server

I need to upload an RHEL image into a Virtual Server of my Bluemix environment.
I downloaded a qcow2 image directly from Red Hat (rhel-server-7.0-x86_64-boot.iso) but whilst this image uploads to a BMX Virtual Server when I try to access the Virtual Server's IP addresses I get no connectivity to it.

I assume this image is not compatible with BMX as a Virtual Server :-(

Does anyone have a RHEL6 or RHEL7 image that does upload as a BMX Virtual Server that I could use to upload myself?

Many Thanks,
Nick

Comment: I re-read your question, you already have a qcow2 type image. What is the machine status? Does it have a public or private IP address?

Comment: Both.

I have setup keys to access it (as with other BMX virtual servers) but all I get is this:

$ ssh -i cloudkey4 ibmcloud@169.50.98.123
ssh: connect to host 169.50.98.123 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: In this case (machine status ok and public IP, but no access) open a support ticket - nothing for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thought this forum was how one got Bluemix support?

To any others reading - if you have a RHEL6 or RHEL7 image that does upload as a BMX Virtual Server please share with me!

Comment: How to open a ticket: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#support

Comment: Thanks Henrik! I will raise one.

Comment: @Nickc909 - Stack Overflow is not a replacement for Bluemix Support. You can ask technical questions here and the community can help.

Answer (score 0):

@nickc909: Check the link http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/obtain-images.html#red-hat-enterprise-linux for Redhat guest images. However you need to have a Redhat Subscription account to install any packages on the VM which is why the default OSs provided are Debian and Centos.

Kailash